# strange rpm --eval command

Tags: linux, rpm

can someone help me understand what is the purpose of running the following command? what does it do?

```
$ sudo rpm --eval "%(/bin/bash >&2)"
```

`man rpm` gives this:

> --eval=’EXPR’
>
> ```
>      Prints macro expansion of EXPR.
> ```

I tried this command, it only shifts user to root, also changed the current
directory of the home directory of user1? why do we want to do this in such a 
mysterious way?

```
[user1@localhost ~]$ sudo rpm --eval "%(/bin/bash >&2)"

root @ localhost : /home/user1 $
```

Answer (score 1):

From: http://rpm.org/user_doc/macros.html

> In addition to the “%{…}” form, shell expansion can be performed using
>   “%(shell command)”. The expansion of “%(…)” is the output of (the
>   expansion of) … fed to /bin/sh. For example, “%(date +%%y%%m%%d)”
>   expands to the string “YYMMDD” (final newline is deleted). Note the
>   2nd % needed to escape the arguments to /bin/date.

Back to your question:

> why do we want to do this in such a mysterious way?

You should ask the author. Maybe there is some side effect he wanted to use. Like executing .bashrc.